# Why rand() function in c++ is not truly random

Tags: c++, random

I have made very simple random function and I'm saving the results in a file. I created two different files whit that program and the information in them is fully equal. Why this is happening?

Here is my simple program:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<cstdlib>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
  {
   ofstream myfile;
   int k;
   myfile.open ("2.txt");
   for(int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++){
   k = rand() % 2;
   myfile << k;
   }
   myfile.close();
 }
```

Comment: Read the docs (and tons of other posts about this topic here).

Comment: Have a look at this reference for [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand).

Comment: will find an answer if you just searched on google  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand()` will generate the same numbers in the same pattern every time unless you seed it first. For that you want to use [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/):

```
srand(5);
rand();

srand(10);
rand(); //will still produce a consistent pattern, but different from rand() seeded with 5
```

If you're looking for something more truly random, try calling `srand` with [your system date/time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) or look into the [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) header if your compiler has C++11 support.

Comment: To make the initialization more random use `srand (time(NULL));`

Comment: Standard random generators won't work in all cases. Monte Carlo algorithms for example.

Comment: @ItayGrudev: Depends on what you mean by "standard". The new `<random>` header does have good PRNG's.

Comment: @MSalters You are correct. Since C++ is evolving with the new standard we get all that included.
I was referring to what he had used which is `<stdlib.h>`'s `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are deterministic. We rely on that fact.

Hence the `rand` function is deterministic

Comment: Well, `rand` could have been written to be non-reproducible by chosing a non-deterministic default seed. It is a design decision.

Comment: @juanchopanza - The algorithm is deterministic. Perhaps the seed could be chosen using time, process id etc. But maybe you can predict that (or have a good bash to work backwards)

Comment: Computers are deterministic, hence there are no nondeterministic algorithms? I'll remember that every time I run a parallel algorithm

Answer (score 1):

In day to day programming the random functions we use are generally pseudo random number generators. Which means the result generated matches a random distribution (chances of out come are distributed evenly) but will always generate the same result on same "seed"

Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness for more detailed description

There are true random simulations such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method to achieve true randomness if needed for more serious task.

You should just assign a different "seed" to your random function each time if you want your result to be random, such as using current date and time.

A bit more on "seed", please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a reasonably good random generator - for example to make things appear random in a game - you can use the classic "Linear Congruent Generator" which is trivial to write and produces pretty random looking output.

The LCG generator:

int seed = 0x533; // chose any number.

int random() { seed = ( seed * 79069 ) + 1;  return seed; }

---

**EDIT:** srand() is what your looking for, he beat me to it